# Owl carousel loading issues (flash of unscaled images and improper item number)

Tags: javascript, debugging, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm having two issues with OwlCarousel when it's loaded on the page.

1. I get a flash of the images not scaled down to their proper
   dimensions before the carousel kicks everything into place.
2. Sometimes on page load the carousel options don't seem to have
   initiated as I get several images per slide rather than just one as
   intended.

Because the images in the carousel are all of a different size but I wanted them centred and the nav buttons to remain in the same place, my main OwlCarousel items are divs with dynamically generated images inside (also using LazySizes JS to lazyload).

My HTML is:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php foreach ($page->pictures()->yaml() as $image): ?>
    <?php if($img = $page->image($image)): ?>
    <div class="owl-holder">
        <img    data-sizes="auto"
                data-srcset="<?= $img->resize(null, 560, 80)->url() ?> 1x,
                <?= $img->url() ?> 2x" alt="<? $page->title()->html()?>"
                data-src="<?= $img->url() ?>"
                src="<?= $img->url() ?>"
                class="lazyload">
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.owl-carousel {
    margin-top:0.75rem;
}

.owl-holder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 35rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-holder img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And the javascript:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
      items: 1,
      margin: 10,
      center: true,
      loop: true,
      nav: true,
  });
```

Plus this function to break the carousel on smaller devices so that images present on top of one another:

```
// Create and play resize function
$(function() {
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel'),
        owlOptions = {
            items: 1,
            margin: 10,
            center: true,
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
        };

    if ( $(window).width() > 897 ) {
        var owlActive = owl.owlCarousel(owlOptions);
    } else {
        owl.addClass('off');
    }

    // Fire on page resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ( $(window).width() > 897 ) {
            if ( $('.owl-carousel').hasClass('off') ) {
                var owlActive = owl.owlCarousel(owlOptions);
                owl.removeClass('off');
            }
        } else {
            if ( !$('.owl-carousel').hasClass('off') ) {
                owl.addClass('off').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
                owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').children(':eq(0)').unwrap();
            }
        }
    });

    // Fire on page load
    if ( $(window).width() < 897 ) {
        owl.addClass('off').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
        owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').children(':eq(0)').unwrap();
    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me identify what's causing this glitch?

The page can be viewed in more detail at tessherb.wwwss46.a2hosted.com